# Custom Dropdown Dialogs (Similar to the Save Dialog)

Tags: objective-c, macos, drop-down-menu, window, save

Is it possible to create your own custom dropdown dialog similar to file save dialogs?  The link below also illustrates it.

[Save Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4fZD.png)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "dropdown dialogs" are called sheets and can be a NSWindow.

The method to make them show up can be found on NSApplication: [beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

A super simple implementation would look look something like this:

```
NSWindowController *sheet = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Sheet"];

[NSApp beginSheet: sheet.window
   modalForWindow: self.view.window // The window from where the sheet will appear
    modalDelegate: self
   didEndSelector: nil // Optional @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:)
      contextInfo: nil];
```